# Debian - Autoinstall Debian distribution via PXE

Tags: linux, debian, pxe

Do u know any method to autoinstall Debian via PXE? ive tryed something similar using SLPOS (Suse Linux Enterprice Point of Service).

i want to load a Clean Debian Distribution from a PXE coz i want it to be Unattended and loaded from a  Intranet, that host cant reach internet to make a network instalation, and btw netinstall needs human interations, i didnt want human interations, i just want to boot, load PXE, that check if it haves a valid debian instalation if not, it loads new one. Same thing like KIWI in SLPOS.

Comment: Have you looked into doing a [net install](https://www.debian.org/CD/netinst/)?  What have you tried?

Comment: Ill add more information, i want to load a Clean Debian Distribution from a PXE coz i want it to be Unattended and loaded from a  Intranet, that host cant reach internet to make a network instalation, and btw netinstall needs human interations, i didnt want human interations, i just want to boot, load PXE, that check if it haves a valid debian instalation if not, it loads new one. Same thing like KIWI in SLPOS.

Answer (score 1):

In order to auto-install Debian via a PXE boot process, there are a number of technologies you require:  pxeboot server (dhcp, tftp, ..), preseed files, ...

I use dnsmasq for the dhcp server, and use debian's netboot.tar.gz for the pxe boot mechanism, and I've built a python script to make adjustments to a debian preseed file.

The steps to totally automate the installation process are quite involved, so I will refer you to

[Auto Build Debian Hosts using PXEBoot and PreSeed files](http://blog.raymond.burkholder.net/index.php?/archives/662-Using-Debian-PreSeed-files-and-a-PXEBoot-Server-to-Auto-Build-Hosts.html)